# Error in Tensorboard's(PyTorch) add_graph

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard, tensorboardx

I'm following this Pytorch's [Tensorboard](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html) documentation.

I have the following code:

```py
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(False)
writer.add_graph(model)
```

It throws the following error:

> _ = model(*args)  # don't catch, just print the error message
>
> TypeError: ResNet object argument after * must be an iterable, not NoneType

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here!

Comment: were you able to find solution to this? I think it is a bug in `add_graph` api.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem too..

Passing an `input_to_model` parameter different from `None` solved the problem. However, I though it should be optional

```
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
writer.add_graph(model, images)
```

Comment: I can't be optional as tb tends to give output shapes at the end of each node. This means, it is necessary that a sample input be given