# PyTorch TensorBoard add_graph() dictionary input error

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

What would be the proper way of passing the PyTorch **dictionary dataset** to the TensorBoard `add_graph(model, data)`.

May seems similar to the [`Question1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021266/error-in-tensorboardspytorch-add-graph), [`Qeustion2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399055/pytorch-decoderrnn-runtimeerror-input-must-have-3-dimensions-got-2) and [`Question3`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-draw-graph-in-tensorboardx-with-a-two-inputs-model/20427), however, couldn't find the right way of handling with dictionary dataset.

**Error Message**

> Dictionary inputs to traced functions must have consistent type. Found Tensor and List[str]
> Error occurs, No graph saved

Below are my anonymized scripts of the project.

`train.py`

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from models import CustomModel
from datasets import CustomDataset
writer = SummaryWriter()

# Dataset
dataset = CustomDataset(params ...)
train_dataset = [dataset[i] for i in range(0, k)]
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

# Model & TensorBoard
model = CustomModel(params....)
writer.add_graph(model, next(iter(train_dataloader)))  # ---- HERE ----
```

`datasets.py`

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.x_sequences = pad_sequence(x_sequences, batch_first=True, padding_value=0)
        self.y_label = torch.LongTensor(label_list)
        ...

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y_label)
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        ...
        return {
            "x_categoricals": self.x_categoricals[index],
            "x_sequences": self.x_sequences[index],
            "y_label": self.y_label[index],
            "info": self.info[index],
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that the entries of the dictionary must all be the same type, but in your case you seem to have a `Tensor` in one entry but a `list` of strings in another entry. You'd have to make sure that all entries have the same type.